# Blank line after deleting contentControl in word

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, office-interop, word-contentcontrol

I'm trying to write in a word document via *VB.net* and for this I'm using *contentControls* in my Word Document but sometimes I have to delete a *contentControl* or another via VB code.

It's kind of easy with `contentcontrol.delete` but when this contentControl contains multipleline and I want to delete it then it leaves a blank line. How can I avoid this?

Comment: you delete only `contentControl object` while keeping CC text in the document, am I right?

Comment: Nop Sorry... My code is `contentcontrol.delete(true)` So I delete the contentcontrol and the CC text but there stays a blank line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will give you some tips based on VBA which I hope you could easily convert to vb.net and your solution.

You need to cover complete range of `ContentControl` including beginning and end of the object. You could do it in this way (VBA code for first CC in activedocument):

```
With ActiveDocument.ContentControls(1)
    'just to make a presentation- let's select range to be deleted
    ActiveDocument.Range(.Range.Start - 1, .Range.End + 2).Select
    'and we delete selection
    Selection.Delete
End With
```

Obviously you could combine `.Select` and `.Delete` lines into one to avoid selection in this way:

```
With.... and so on
    ActiveDocument.Range(.Range.Start - 1, .Range.End + 2).Delete
End with
```

Comment: Very Nice it worked perfectly. And the second code is shorter and works too..
Thanks

Comment: Where do the -1 and +2 come from?  How do you know this won't delete text instead of just formatting?

Comment: this is just a suggestion, you should make some experiments on that. Solution assumes that you have spaces before and after ContentControl therefore +2 remove additional space. But as I said- make some tests before implementation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for solution. `.Range.Start - 1` is `ActiveDocument.ContentControls(1).Range` ?

Comment: yes, it is `ActiveDocument.ContentControls(1).Range.Start -1`