# Remove Blank line after deleting contentControl in word

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I have a word template, and trying to write in it. I'm using `ContentControl` for change or remove some text.

I'm using this code to change the text or delete it.

```
Object oTemplatePath = Server.MapPath("~/DietTemplate/" + template.FileName);
oWordDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(ref oTemplatePath, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
foreach (ContentControl content in oWordDoc.ContentControls)
 {
  var field = fieldlist.Where(e => e.DietFields.Name == content.Title);
  if (field.Single().Value != null)
   content.Range.Text = field.Single().Value;
  else
  content.Delete(true);
  }
```

This will delete the content but add a blank line in it.

I use this code instead of 'Delete':

```
oWordDoc.Range( content.Range.Start, content.Range.End).Delete(true);
```

but get error.

How can i remove this blank line?

Comment: Duplicate, just in other language. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17450713/blank-line-after-deleting-contentcontrol-in-word

Comment: I use this, but get error.

Comment: take a look into my question. May help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35605776/removing-the-line-where-a-content-control-is. See all the edits on the answer, one of them may help you.